# replicated HSQLDB

Tags: database, grails, hsqldb

We're reviewing different DB engines to be used in our spring java project (actually grails project). Neither of `real DB` `MySQL/PostgreSQL` support clustering out of the box (it's still possbile to cluster DB instances using 3rd party software). 
I'm thinking of using `HSQLDB` locally on each server and replicate them using `HSQLDB-R` (via `JGroups`). The size of every database won't exceed few hudnreds of megabytes. 
Could someone tell me what hidden problems I should expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clustering with HSQLDB, use http://ha-jdbc.sourceforge.net/

HSQLDB/R was a proof-of-concept project, based on JGroups communications. HA-JDBC is a production system that uses JGroups and supports HSQLDB.

Medium sized databases (less than 1GB) are commonly deployed in production using HSQLDB.

Answer (score 1):

[H2](http://h2database.com/) has clustering support built in - see http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#clustering. I haven't used it extensively so I can't comment on issues, but it worked fine in my tests. Plus H2 is a significantly better implementation overall vs HSQLDB.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish with the database cluster?  If redundancy is your primary objective, then you could have multiple MySQL instances using replication in a master-slave setup.  If the master fails, then you can automatically promote the slave to be the master.  If your application is read-intensive you'll also be able to see a performance increase as the slaves can serve up database reads.  There is quite a lot of good information about this [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807309).

Comment: I'm only looking for simplest failure-tolerant solution. So, simple periodical replication is enough for me.